# CSS menu broken in Firefox (display:table-cell;)

Tags: css, firefox, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

HTML:

```
<td align="center" width="100%">
<a class="Forum_ib_moderate" href="Default.aspx" title="Moderate"></a>
<a class="Forum_ib_admin" href="Default.aspx" title="Admin"></a>
...
```

CSS:

```
A.Forum_ib_moderate:link, A.Forum_ib_moderate:visited, A.Forum_ib_moderate:active, A.Forum_ib_moderate:hover
{
background-image: url(images/ib_moderate.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
display:table-cell;
}

A.Forum_ib_admin:hover
{
background-image: url(images/ib_admin_hover.png);

}
```

the menu looks just fine in IE, shows up vertical in Firefox. If i turn off "display:table-cell;" style in Firebug and then turn it back on, it fixes that menu node.

[image]

any ideas?

p.s.: i don't want to mess with the menu itself, since it's a part of a DNN Forum 4.4.3. I'd rather fix the CSS to make it show correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I think you'll find that IE works because it **ignores** `display: table-cell`.  `Display: table-cell` is actually you're problem.

What I'm guessing is happening is that IE is reverting those to be inline element, hence horizontal.

Change it to:

```
display: inline;
```

add some padding (left and right) as necessary and you'll get what you want.

Alternatively you can float them (left and/or right).

Besdies, they're already in a table cell.  Table cell display inside that is a bit wrong.

Comment: i knew this had to be easy :) thanx

Comment: Yes, trying to display a table-cell directly inside a table-cell is invalid, absolutely anything could happen.

Answer (score 0):

We've run into this issue as well. Still looking for a solution. In our case, we need to keep display: table-cell layout.

It appears Firefox sometimes and seemingly randomly, will cause table-cell objects to wrap rather than act like an actual table. A REFRESH fixes it, which just makes it that more difficult to bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a simple FireFox bug. I encountered the problem the other way around: The DIVs with table-cell arranged below each other *after* the refresh in FF 3.5.9 on Win XP.

I was not able to not find any solution (wrap the cells into a row, overflow hidden, etc) but to update FireFox to 3.6.3 and hope there are few users with that version.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to a firefox reflow bug that I'm trying to fix as well.  Apparently tables are really bad for rendering, since they cause a reflow and it seems that Firefox sometimes misses the reflows.

I found the following pages to be helpful:

- http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/
- http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html